# How to work with multiple of the same key?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a large dictionary that contains weather data. You can take a look at it [here](https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?zip=23060&appid=5bbaad9fc9a116bc91fabc376a61c731)

This weather data is for multiple days, and I want to get all of the values from one key. How would I do this?
Here is a simplified version of the dictionary:

```
'data': { 'day1' : {'weather_discription': 'cloudy'},
          'day2' : {'weather_discription': 'clear'} 
}
```

I tried to use this code:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('data website')
res = r.json()
print(res['weather_discription'])
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] of the simplified dataset and *your attempt to implement this*.

Comment: Well, which key? And what part of your code do you have problem with?

Comment: If you can have multiples of it, it's not a "key" in the usual sense of the word.

Comment: ok, I made a simplified version

Comment: Loop over all the entries in `res['data']`

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop to get them all.

```
for day, data in res['data'].items():
    print(f"Weather on {day} was {data['weather_description']}")
```

Comment: What exactly does the day, data do?

Comment: `day` gets the keys, `data` gets the values, of the dictionary being iterated over.

Comment: could they be changed based on the values in the real data?

Comment: They're just variable names, you can call them anything you want.

Comment: `for key, value in res['data'].items():`